# How to create horizontal carousel in iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Recently I have switched to iOS from Android world. I have seen two options for creating horizontal sliders. My goal is to create an horizontal slider of cards present on this image. [image: horizontal viewpager cards] I got confused which element need to the best option in iOS. Should I use CollectionView for this OR should I use PageViewController for this?
Since I am beginner I cannot use library at this stage with limited knowledge I have. Please suggest me how should I do it

Comment: UICollectionView with a custom flow layout

Comment: I have like 60-70 elements where each element will have image to display with indicators. If i use Collection view there is no inbuilt indicator function but if i use pageviewcontroller there is count function which provide me indicator. do i need to manually write the code for indicator as well ?

Comment: Yes. With 60-70 elements you would likely want custom code / design for the indicator anyway, otherwise you'd have 60-70 little dots at the bottom of the screen. CollectionView is well suited for this design as it reuses cells for performance reasons.

Comment: If you are happy using open source code, take a look at iCarousel

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Short answer

You should use a UICollectionView.

### More detailed answer

1) Setup the horizontal layout with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
// The size of each item. Pick a suitable height so that the items do not get stacked:
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 2, height: view.frame.height)
// The most important part:
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
// Then initialize collectionView
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

2) Setup scaling (pseudocode)

i. Have `self` implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView)`

ii. Set `collectionView.delgate = self`

iii. In `scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView)`, get all visible cells by casting `scrollView as! UICollectionView` and getting `visibleCells` property.

iv. For cell in visible cells, set appropriate scale (of the cell contents, *not of the cell itself*) with `CGAffineTransform` given cell's distance from the horizontal center of the screen. This may take some arithmetic; this should work just fine:

```
s = −0.00005 * pow(cell.center.x, 2) + 1.5
```

---

Hope this helps! Feel free to ask for clarification if you need it.

Comment: How do you actually set the scale?

Comment: Yeah i tried using ```CGAffineTransformMakeScale```, it doesn't work .

Comment: For @Supertecnoboff, and future reference, check the edit to 2.iv.

Comment: can u explain your scaling formula?

Comment: @AmberK, sorry for the late response. The idea is to have a downward-opening parabola that is a function for the scale. I chose the values just by experimenting.

Comment: @AmberK, play around with the function. Maybe put a horizontal shift in. It’s not a one size fits all—the screen width and desired scaling matter a lot.

Comment: @Daniel this answer just helped solve an issue I was having accessing the collectionView cell properties from the scrollViewDidEndDecelerating function, an issue I've been at for a month now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried CollectionView for the carousel slideshow, but it didn't work out for me. I didn't like the hackish ways I had to do to make it show images in one row and I also didn't like the fact that it cannot return the active image (there is some workaround here as well, but they don't seem reliable). So, naturally, I ended up building a custom slideshow carousel for my purpose. I will share the code here, so hopefully, it can help(or at least guide someone) with a similar problem.

NOTE: My carousel is full width, singleImagePerScreen carousel, with a swipe recognizer to swipe through images and delegate function that is triggered when an image is active(I use it to display active image - "1 of 5").

TESTED ON: SWIFT 5, XCode 12.2, iOS 14.2

```
// ImageCarouselView class

import UIKit

class ImageCarouselView: UIView {
    private let images: [UIImage?]
    private var index = 0
    private let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var delegate: ImageCarouselViewDelegate?

    lazy var previousImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    lazy var currentImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    lazy var nextImageView = imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

    lazy var previousImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return previousImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: -screenWidth)
    }()

    lazy var currentImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return currentImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
    }()

    lazy var nextImageLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = {
        return nextImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: screenWidth)
    }()

    init(_ images: [UIImage?]) {
        self.images = images

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        setupLayout()
        setupImages()
        setupSwipeRecognizer()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })

        addSubview(previousImageView)
        addSubview(currentImageView)
        addSubview(nextImageView)

        previousImageLeadingConstraint = previousImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: -screenWidth)
        currentImageLeadingConstraint = currentImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
        nextImageLeadingConstraint = nextImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: screenWidth)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            previousImageLeadingConstraint,
            previousImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            previousImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),

            currentImageLeadingConstraint,
            currentImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            currentImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),

            nextImageLeadingConstraint,
            nextImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            nextImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth),
        ])
    }

    private func setupImages() {
        currentImageView.image = images[self.index]

        guard images.count > 1 else { return }

        if (index == 0) {
            previousImageView.image = images[images.count - 1]
            nextImageView.image = images[index + 1]
        }

        if (index == (images.count - 1)) {
            previousImageView.image = images[index - 1]
            nextImageView.image = images[0]
        }
    }

    private func setupSwipeRecognizer() {
        guard images.count > 1 else { return }

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes))
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        self.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
    }

    @objc private func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .left) {
            showNextImage()
        }

        if (sender.direction == .right) {
            showPreviousImage()
        }
    }

    private func showPreviousImage() {
        previousImageLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        currentImageLeadingConstraint.constant = screenWidth

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.nextImageView = self.currentImageView
            self.currentImageView = self.previousImageView
            self.previousImageView = self.imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

            self.index = self.index == 0 ? self.images.count - 1 : self.index - 1
            self.delegate?.imageCarouselView(self, didShowImageAt: self.index)
            self.previousImageView.image = self.index == 0 ? self.images[self.images.count - 1] : self.images[self.index - 1]

            self.setupLayout()
        })
    }

    private func showNextImage() {
        nextImageLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
        currentImageLeadingConstraint.constant = -screenWidth

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.previousImageView = self.currentImageView
            self.currentImageView = self.nextImageView
            self.nextImageView = self.imageView(image: nil, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)

            self.index = self.index == (self.images.count - 1) ? 0 : self.index + 1
            self.delegate?.imageCarouselView(self, didShowImageAt: self.index)
            self.nextImageView.image = self.index == (self.images.count - 1) ? self.images[0] : self.images[self.index + 1]

            self.setupLayout()
        })
    }

    func imageView(image: UIImage? = nil, contentMode: UIImageView.ContentMode) -> UIImageView {
        let view = UIImageView()

        view.image = image
        view.contentMode = contentMode
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return view
    }
}

// ImageCarouselViewDelegate

import UIKit

protocol ImageCarouselViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func imageCarouselView(_ imageCarouselView: ImageCarouselView, didShowImageAt index: Int)
}

// Usage

let slideshowView = ImageCarouselView(images) // initialize

self.slideshowView.delegate = self // set delegate in viewDidLoad()

extension YourViewController: ImageCarouselViewDelegate {
    func imageCarouselView(_ imageCarouselView: ImageCarouselView, didShowImageAt index: Int) {
        // do something with index
    }
}
```